# Deleting aged rows from postgresql table which don't have related entries in another table

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3, maintenance

I maintain a website where users post interesting links, and other users leave replies under the said links. I want to delete **aged** link entries under which **no one replied**.

The postgresql database is like so: there's a table called `links_link`, and another one called `links_publicreply`. `links_publicreply` has a column called `answer_to`, which is a foreign key to `links_link`. I only want to delete aged rows in `links_link` which do NOT have a related entry in `links_publicreply`.

What would the queries be? Something like the following?

```
begin;
DELETE FROM links_link WHERE id NOT IN links_publicreply AND "submitted_on" < now() - interval('1 day'); 
commit;
```

I don't want to run into foreign key violations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subrequest : this should work

```
DELETE FROM links_link WHERE id NOT IN (select answer_to from links_publicreply ) AND `submitted_on` < CURRENT_DATE-1 ;
```

You can have of course multiple subrequest chained.

Comment: Hmm, so I tried `DELETE FROM links_link WHERE id NOT IN (select "answer_to" from links_publicreply) AND "submitted_on" < now() - interval '1 hour';` which is more or less what you suggested, but I'm getting the error: `current transaction is aborted, commands ignored until end of transaction block`. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you run it in a begin / commit ? or just directly ?

Comment: I ran it in begin / commit, out of habit.

Comment: You should have a look at this so
http://laurenthinoul.com/how-to-fix-postgres-error-current-transaction-is-aborted-commands-ignored-until-end-of-transaction-block/